# How to install/run a node module from Windows cmd

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, geojson, overpass-api

Very big 'node' noob here. Just trying to get the lay of the land. I've installed node and the npm package manager based the excellent instructions found [here](http://blog.gvm-it.eu/post/20404719601/getting-started-with-node-js-on-windows). I can verify I have everything (node-wise) installed okay - with a user variable set to PATH =C:\Users\Dude\AppData\Roaming\npm

Using npm I installed

```
npm install -g query-overpass
npm install -g geojsonio
```

And verified that both had .cmd files and stuff show up here:

C:\Users\Dude\AppData\Roaming\npm

then from the cmd I put in the [example](https://github.com/perliedman/query-overpass)

```
echo '[out:json];node(57.7,11.9,57.8,12.0)[amenity=bar];out;' | query-overpass
```

and got

```
{ message: 'Request failed: HTTP 400', statusCode: 400 }
```

Is there something I am missing here regarding installing node modules and how to run them (in Windows)? Is a .js file calling the modules what is required?

Comment: I get the the same error on my machine, see @Brad answer

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think there is an issue with your node modules?  The error message is very clearly an HTTP error message, indicating a problem with the query you're making.  Your modules are installed fine.

I don't know what your modules do, but you should try different parameters and contact the person that wrote them to indicate that their example no longer works.